# JavaScript: Iterate JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

JSON string:

```
'["Colour","Audio","Effect"]'
```

I'm having an issue iterating through this, albeit it's a simple solution. I have tried:

```
for (var o in obj) { } // iterates through each individual character of the json object

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { } // same as above

$.each(obj, function(i, v) { }); // same as above
```

I'm not seeing something here. So hopefully someone out there can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This is a simple `array`, not `json`.

Comment: It is a string. Note how I don't instantiate it into an array. Please understand the code next time.

Comment: @BrianGraham: Certainly you understand that there can be ambiguity between posting JavaScript and JSON structures. It's helpful if you make it explicit by calling it something like *server-side JSON markup*.

Comment: Strings are normally enclosed in quotation marks. If you receive this as response from an Ajax call, then yes it will probably be a string in JavaScript. All you to have to do is to parse it into an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Brian, what you posted looks like a literal array, not a JSON object. Please be more careful explaining your code next time. It's probably  an AJAX response, in which case it is made into a string by XHR, but you did not mention anything like that

Comment: Are you sure you are iterating over an object or an array, it sounds like the the "JSON" in your question is just a string that hasnt been parsed, which seems to be misleading people. Did you mean `"[\"Colour\",\"Audio\",\"Effect\"]"` rather than `["Colour","Audio","Effect"]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, parse the JSON string:

```
var jsonStr = '["Colour","Audio","Effect"]';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

// Alternatively, write out the JSON directly
// var obj = ["Colour","Audio","Effect"];
```

Then, either

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { }
```

or

```
$.each(obj, function(i, v) { });
```

`for (var o in obj) { }` iterates over the arrays's raw properties, including `length`, and is not suitable for iterating over an array.

Comment: It's not json string, it's an array of strings.

Comment: @gdoron It may be a JSON string if the first code block is a representation of said string and not JavaScript code. Note how I defined it in the very first line of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to declare your obj variable:

```
var obj = ["Colour","Audio","Effect"];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
    alert(obj[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse a JSON string before you can use it.

`["Colour","Audio","Effect"]` is an array, `'["Colour","Audio","Effect"]'` is a string.

You need to use `JSON.parse('["Colour","Audio","Effect"]')` (or `$.parseJSON`) to convert the JSON string into a usable JavaScript array.

```
var obj = '["Colour","Audio","Effect"]';
$.each(obj, function(i, v) {
   console.log(v); // prints each letter
});

var obj = ["Colour","Audio","Effect"]; // or $.parseJSON('["Colour","Audio","Effect"]')
$.each(obj, function(i, v) {
   console.log(v); // prints each element
});
```